# String literal and Char array

Tags: c++

```
char i[6] = "Hello"; //EXAMPLE 1
const char *p =   "Hello"; //EXAMPLE 2 
char q[6] = i; //EXAMPLE 3 
char s[6] = (*(&i)); //EXAMPLE 4
```

`"Hello"`  is a string literal, which has a type of  `const char[6]`  which is converted to
`const char*`  ( like in EXAMPLE 2 )

1 - Why does not this conversion happen in EXAMPLE 1 ?

2 - How can  a value of type `const char[6]` be used to initialize an entity of type `char[6]` ( in EXAMPLE 1 ) ?

3 - EXAMPLE 3 will cause an error because of `Array-to-pointer decay` , right ?

4 - EXAMPLE 4 will cause an error because of `Array-to-pointer decay` , right ?

Comment: In example 1, elements of the string literal are used to initialize elements of the array. It is equivalent to writing `char i[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};`. That is, in example 1 there is no conversion. This answers you 1st and 2nd question. Moreover, in example 3 `i` decays to `char*` which cannot be used as initializer to initialize a `char [6]` array.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246132/discussion-on-question-by-f877576-string-literal-and-char-array).